# Magneto continues to use old URLs after moved to staging

Tags: php, magento, caching, magento-1.7

I'm setting up a staging server at the moment. I copied the live db and codebase over, and I've changed the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in the db.

I've also updated the `web/cookie/cookie_domain` to staging.site.com (where the prod is currently www.site.com, and dev is dev.site.com),

I've turned all caching off by setting all related values in the db to 0. I've checked all the tmp directories on the server to see if cache was being written somewhere else, but found that it doesn't seem to be.

I've reindexed multiple times, and waited a day to see if the server was just being unfriendly with cache. I've also tried to access the domain on multiple computers using private browsing.

At first, the issue was that the site kept redirecting to the LIVE. I tried changing the admin URL, by setting the `use_custom_admin_path` to 1, and updating the local.xml file, which resulted in a 404 for the admin. We aren't using memcache or apc AFAIK.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like `app/etc/local.xml` is still pointed at the old database. Also, if you kept a copy of the old `local.xml` with a `.xml` extension, alphabetical last file wins and overwrites the settings in the previous files.

Comment: It's not. This was the first thing that was changed. The DB is a copy of the OLD db. Is this unwise?

Comment: I've ensured only one local.xml file exists in the app/etc folder, as well.

Comment: Have you deleted the cache files explicitly?

Comment: Absolutely. Removed var/cache/* and var/session/*.

Comment: if you are using apache, have you checked you don't have any rewrite rules in htaccess ?